# qBittorrent global menu icon shows in the top left corner of the screen

Tags: unity, icons, qbittorrent

About a week ago, after update, qBittorrent's icon that is supposed to be on the right side with other applications, started showing in the left corner as shown on the image below:

[image]

I did not mind this at first, thinking it would solve itself with another update, but as you can imagine, it became very annoying since it makes me unable to close any app with cross.

Can this be solved by some command(s), editing settings in Unity Tweak Tool or something similar?

Information:
Ubuntu version: 14.04.1
Kernel version: 4.4.0-87-generic

```
$ apt-cache policy qbittorrent
qbittorrent:
  Installed: 3.3.15-0ppa1~trusty
  Candidate: 3.3.15-0ppa1~trusty
  Version table:
 *** 3.3.15-0ppa1~trusty 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.1.11-1~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     3.1.8-2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: @EliahKagan Post updated

Comment: I too have this issue, you have an success?